# If condition in SQL file vertica

Tags: sql, vertica

I need to execute insertions for around 10 tables, before inserting I have to check for a condition, condition remains the same for each of the tables, instead of giving that condition within insert query, I wish I could give in if condition (a select query), if satisfied then execute insert statements, is there a way to give if condition in Vertica SQL file ? If condition is not satisfied I dont want to execute any of the insert queries.

Answer (score 0):

If the condition is, for example, that you only insert the data on a Sunday, try this:

a) a test table:

```
    CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE input(id,name)
    ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS AS
              SELECT 42,'Arthur Dent'
    UNION ALL SELECT 43,'Ford Prefect'
    UNION ALL SELECT 44,'Tricia McMillan'
    KSAFE 0;
```

From this table, select with a `WHERE` condition that tests whether it's sunday -- that's all, see here:

```
    SELECT
      *
    FROM input
    WHERE TRIM(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE,'Day'))='Sunday'
    ;

    id|name
    42|Arthur Dent
    43|Ford Prefect
    44|Tricia McMillan
```

With a different value for the week day (I'm writing this on a Sunday...), you get this:

```
    SELECT
      *
    FROM input
    WHERE TRIM(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE,'Day'))='Monday'
    ;

    id|name
    select succeeded; 0 rows fetched
```

I use this technique in SQL generating SQL to create a script or an empty file determining on circumstances, and then to call that script (full or empty), implementing a conditional SQL execution that way....

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old post, but i want to share what i recently solved my problem.

I need to insert in one table or another based on some condition. You first should have a field or value what will be your search condition.

```
create table tmp1 (
    Col1        int null
    ,Col2       varchar(100) null
)

--Insert values
insert into tmp (Col1,Col2) Values
    (1,'Text1')
    ,(2,'Text2')

--Insert into table001
insert into table001
select
    t.field1
    ,t.field2
    ,......
from table1 t
inner join tmp t2
    on t2.col1 = t.ColX
where 1 = case when t2.Col2 = 'Text1' then 1 else 0 end --Search condition; if 1<>0 then it doesn't do anything; otherwise insert.

--Insert into table002
insert into table002
select
    t.field1
    ,t.field2
    ,......
from table2 t
inner join tmp t2
    on t2.col1 = t.ColX
where 1 = case when t2.Col2 = 'Text2' then 1 else 0 end --Search condition; if 1<>0 then it doesn't do anything; otherwise insert.
```

Or you can use an UNION/UNION ALL based on this if it is the same working table.

Regards!